# Subversion post-commit failing!

Tags: svn, post-commit-hook

I have just got subversion up running, but my post-commit.tmpl is failing.

I want to update my live directory at every trunk commit, so i always can see the new working code. Although this seems to work when i lunch the update by ssh, but not in the template file.

This is what i got in my post-commit.tmpl:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

/usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/commit-email.pl \
  "$REPOS" "$REV" commit-watchers@example.org

svn update /var/www/vhosts/mysite.nu/devlive >> /var/www/vhosts/mysite.nu/log/log-dev-live
```

Furthermore i get nothing in the log.

I have changed all permissions to the directories towards my webserver user (www-data) and chmod 777.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `PATH` variable may not be set you need to use the full path to `svn` here (like `/usr/bin/svn`).

Also, IIRC the file should be named `post-commit`, not `post-commit.tmpl` (which is just a template, an example on how you can do it).

Comment: unfortunately still no luck! Since SVN is running under Apache, i should assume that the user controlling the executions are www-data? I dont have a svnserve user.

Comment: @JavaCake: You can find out by adding a line like this: `whoami >/tmp/svn-user.txt`

Comment: still no luck, the file is totally empty `-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data      0 2011-06-25 15:02 svn-user.txt`

Comment: i just deleted the directory and created the svn again and it worked. Makes no sense, but im happy.